# Sort List of objects by date and applying filter

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, java-8, comparator

I have list of Payments:

```
Payment 1
  CountyTaxAmount = 250.00
  CityTaxAmount   = 101.00
  LienAmount      = 0.00
  HazardAmount    = 0.00
  PaymentDueDate  = "2018-06-01"

Payment 2
  CountyTaxAmount = 10.00
  CityTaxAmount = 20.00
  LienAmount      = 0.00
  HazardAmount    = 0.00
  PaymentDueDate = "2018-05-01"
```

I created a function that takes in this list and `currentDueDate`.
If `paymentDueDate` is **equal to** or **before** `currentDueDate` and one that's closest to `currentDueDate`, I want to use that row in my calculations.

For some reason my sort is not working properly.
Can someone shed some light on what I am doing wrong.
Here is my code:

```
private EscrowStatusEnum determineEscrowStatus(Payment pcm, LocalDate currentDueDate) {
    EscrowStatusEnum escrowStatus = null;

    if(currentDueDate!= null && pcm!=null 
            && pcm.getPayment() != null 
            && !pcm.getPayment().isEmpty()) {

        Predicate<Payment> pcmRow = 
                it->it.getPaymentDueDate()!=null && !it.getPaymentDueDate().isAfter(currentDueDate);

        final Payment sortedRow = 
                pcm.getPayment().stream().sorted((el1, el2) -> el1.getPaymentDueDate().compareTo(el2.getPaymentDueDate())).
                filter(pcmRow).findFirst().orElse(null);

        if(sortedRow != null) {

            BigDecimal countyCityLienHazardSum = sortedRow.getCountyTaxAmount().add(sortedRow.getCityTaxAmount()).add(sortedRow.getLienAmount()).add(sortedRow.getHazardAmount());
            BigDecimal countyCityLienSum = sortedRow.getCountyTaxAmount().add(sortedRow.getCityTaxAmount()).add(sortedRow.getLienAmount());

            if(countyCityLienHazardSum.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0)
                escrowStatus = EscrowStatusEnum.NONESCROWED;
            else if(countyCityLienSum.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0 && sortedRow.getHazardAmount().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0 ||
                    countyCityLienSum.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) >= 0 && sortedRow.getHazardAmount().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0)
                escrowStatus = EscrowStatusEnum.ESCROWED;
        }
    }

    return escrowStatus;
}
```

When I pass in `currentDueDate` of `"2018-06-01"`, I want my code to return `Payment 1`.

Currently it is returning `Payment 2`.

If I remove `Payment 2` from my tests, then it returns `Payment 1`.

So something must be wrong with sort.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your sort returns the **earliest** date.  What you want is the **latest** date that is earlier than the cutoff.

To find the smallest or largest value in a stream, don't use `sort(...).findFirst()`.  Use [`max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) or [`min`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#min-java.util.Comparator-) instead.  In your case:

```
sortedRow = pcm.getPayment().stream()
               .filter(pcmRow)
               .max(Comparator.comparing(Payment::getPaymentDueDate))
               .orElse(null);   // not relevant to your question but consider not using nulls so much
```

Comment: @Bohemian I do want row where dates are equal

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the filter:

```
!it.getPaymentDueDate().isAfter(currentDueDate)
```

This allows the payment due date to be *the same* as the current due date, but you only want *overdue* payments.

Change it to this:

```
it.getPaymentDueDate().isBefore(currentDueDate)
```